# grep in python properly

Tags: python, bash

I am used to do scripting in `bash`, but I am also learning `python`.
So, as a way of learning, I am trying to modify my few old bash in python. As, say,I have a file, with line like:

```
TOTDOS= 0.38384E+02n_Ef= 0.81961E+02 Ebnd 0.86883E+01
```

to get the value of `TOTDOS` in bash, I just do:

```
grep "TOTDOS=" 630/out-Dy-eos2|head -c 19|tail -c 11
```

but by python, I am doing:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import re
import os.path
import sys

f1 = open("630/out-Dy-eos2", "r")
re1 = r'TOTDOS=\s*(.*)n_Ef=\s*(.*)\sEbnd'
for line in f1:
    match1 = re.search(re1, line)
    if match1:
        TD = (match1.group(1))
f1.close()
print(TD)
```

Which is surely giving correct result, but seems to be much more then bash(not to mention problem with `regex`).

Question is, am I overworking in python, or missing something of it?

Comment: what output do you expect?

Comment: Unless you really need complex pattern matching, use `if substring in line` - much faster and easier to read. That being said, there are certain things that are simply easier to do in bash: Line based filtering is one of them.

Comment: using `if substring in line` is not going to extract the value

Comment: @PadraicCunningham neither will `grep`

Comment: @LukasGraf, the OP is assigning to a variable so I presume as stated in the question they want the value

Comment: @PadraicCunningham sure. I'm just pointing out here that for the very common use case of simple substring matching, there's a simple and idiomatic solution in Python. It's a comment, not an answer.

Comment: If all the lines are in similar format `[x for x in line.split() if x[-1].isdigit()]` will do the same thing

Answer (score 0):

A python script that matches your bash line would be more like this:

```
with open('630/out-Dy-eos2', 'r') as f1:
    for line in f1:
        if "TOTDOS=" in line:
            print line[8:19]
```

Looks a little bit better now.

Answer (score 0):

> [...] but seems to be much more than bash

Maybe (?) generators are the closest Python concept to the "pipe filtering" used in shell.

```
import itertools

#
# Simple generator to iterate through a file
# equivalent of line by line reading from an input file
def source(fname):
    with open(fname,"r") as f:
        for l in f:
            yield l


src = source("630/out-Dy-eos2")

# First filter to keep only lines containing the required word
# equivalent to `grep -F`
filter1 = (l for l in src if "TOTDOS=" in l)

# Second filter to keep only line in the required range
# equivalent of `head -n ... | tail -n ...`
filter2 = itertools.islice(filter1, 10, 20,1)


# Finally output
output = "".join(filter2)
print(output)
```

Concerning your specific example, if you need it, you could use regexp in a generator:

```
re1 = r'TOTDOS=\s*(.*)n_Ef=\s*(.*)\sEbnd'
filter1 = (m.group(1) for m in (re.match(re1, l) for l in src) if m)
```

Those are only (some of the) basic building blocs available to you.